# Sudden 404 pages on product category archives

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, rewrite-rules, 404-error

For no apparent reasons, wordpress is returning 404 error on pages that were working fine. Affected pages are *product category* archive pages. They are a mixture of custom and default pages.

The directory structures that are affected

> ```
> example.com/product-category/   
>
> example.com/product-category/some-sub-category-name
> ```

**Steps already taken**

1. Checked plugins compatibility even though no new plugins were installed prior to that
2. Checked mod_rewrite rules on .htaccess
3. Reset permalinks settings to default and back to custom
4. Cleared cache
5. Renamed the categories
6. Delete and reworked on the affected pages

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do any recent Plugin, Theme and or WP Core updates?  By any chance do you have a Backup from when it was working.  I have been able to troubleshoot these types of "out of nowhere" bugs by comparing a BU in a good state to the current bad state.

Comment: @mikerojas Thanks! it is solved. I have forgotten to double check if I have that product category set up! I assumed I did. Such a straight forward thing and I overlooked spending almost 2 days on this. *face palm*